# Hint doesn't disappear on EditText click

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText`:

```
<EditText 
    android:hint="Your Notes" android:id="@+id/tv_notes_data"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" style="@style/items_description_plain" />
```

I need the hint to disappear when user clicks on it, but this never happen. Please advice why.

Comment: This is by design. The hint is not meant to disappear when you click the `EditText`. It will disappear when it contains at least one character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use an `onClickListener`:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
    void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setHint("");
        // or ((EditText) v).setHint(""));
    }
});
```

For setting the hint again, you can use:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener {
    void OnFocusChange(params) {
        editText.setHint("Your Notes");
    }
});
```

By the way, the hint disappears only when the user starts typing. In fact, while there is no characters in the `EditText`, the hint is shown.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a lightly improved answer than @NitroG42's...  Here's my solution:

```
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            editText.setHint("");
            return false;
        }

    });

    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                editText.setHint("Hint");
            }
        }
    });
```

hope this helps someone